# how can I make my application to wait for specific time from mvp4g view?

Tags: java, gwt, sleep, wait, mvp4g

I am using GWT + MVP4G,
In my application I want to make my application to wait for specific amount of time from mvp4g view.
I tried Timer but it doesn't work.
please suggest me some solution if anyone knows.....thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try the Scheduler from GWT but the GWT Timer seems still more appropriate.

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(yourCommand, msToWait);
```